# SQL Server - Error 3202 during Restore

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

While attempting to restore a 4 TB MDF/data database with a 1.8 TB LDF/log file, I'm receiving the following error:

`Write on '???' failed: 1117 (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
Error: 3202, Severity: 16, State: 1`

The backup appears to have created successfully on the primary machine, but will not restore to the backup machine. Both servers are running the SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition. The location of the .LDF transaction log file is being moved during the restore from the primary's I drive to the backups L drive, but this never posed an issue in the past.

The database is made up of 3 .MDF files: one approximately 2 TB, another at 1.4 TB, and another around 300 GB. The .LDF transaction log file is about 1.8TB. The restore locations have enough space, with the drive for the .mdf files having 6 TB total and the drive for .ldf having 2 TB total.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

FYI:  This article is also posted in StackOverflow at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116806/sql-server-restore-error-3202
I'm uncertain which location is best for this type of question.

Comment: can you please answer the following questions: 1) can you please check the account that "SQL VSS Writer service" is running under ( if its under another user please switch it to local admin)
2) are you using any of Symantec software's (AV, backup,..etc)?

Comment: Have you done any low-level analysis of the disk(s) on the backup server? Also, please don't cross-post the same question to multiple SE sites. This just creates more work for everyone.

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna, SQL VSS Writer service is running with the following settings:  `Startup Type = "Automatic"; Service Status = "Started"; Log On = "Local System Account"`.  Under Log On, `"Allow service to interact with desktop" = unchecked`.  I'm not sure if that setting has a bearing on this though.

We are not using any Symantec software on this server per my knowledge.

Comment: A suggestion I received was to check that Write Caching was enabled on the HDD, which it wasn't, so I enabled it.  I reran the Restore, but unfortunately had the same outcome.  Here is SQL Server's output at the time time of failure:

`95 percent processed.
96 percent processed.
97 percent processed.
Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Write on "???" failed: 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.`

Comment: There was also a Windows Log error entry at the same time: `The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR1`.  I'm guessing this means it has something to do with the disk this is on?

Comment: At this point this is either a faulty disk or, in case of misconfiguration, a Server Fault question.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  The system admin found a fault on the disk.  Thanks for all the help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the error message posted in the comments this is a faulty disk that cannot serve write requests (at a certain location).

Comment: That was the issue. The LUN was wiped out and recreated and now the errors are gone. Thanks everyone for the assistance.